# Alternative to deprecated method using Google Forms with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-forms

Since I'm fairly new to Python 3 I wanted to create a simple Flask App that converts Google Forms to tables using Pandas. Which normally would be rather simple, but every tutorial I have found is similar to [this example](http://pbpython.com/pandas-google-forms-part1.html) from pbpython.com.

The problem is that almost every tutorial uses `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` from the module `oauth2client.client` which isn't supported anymore.

So my question has two parts based on that problem (because I couldn't find an answer using Google).

1) Is there an alternative to `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials`?

2) If my Google Form is open to the public, do I really need Oauth 2? Because as I said it is an example.

TL;DR: I don't know what to use since `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` is unavailable and I need someone more experienced than me to suggest me a working example of a Python+Google Forms **in case my question has already been answered**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the up to date code
https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/401

```
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        p12_key_path,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
    )

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    service = apiclient.discovery.build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)
```